# Update access database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access

I have page where on Page_Load I populate some textbox and dropdownlist with data I getting from the database, I getting the data right, but when I click the button to save the new data it take the old data and not the new data for the update.

I putting my code:
Page_load:

```
string id = Request.QueryString["id"];

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =" + Server.MapPath("path to DB"));
        OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand("select * from table where ID=" + id, conn);
        OleDbDataReader reader;

        conn.Open();
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();


        ddlType.SelectedIndex = (Convert.ToInt32(reader["PersonType"]) - 1); // -1 to fix position, list is zero based. type 1(0) = PP type 2(1) = DC

        txtFirstName.Text = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
        txtLastName.Text = reader["LastName"].ToString();
        txtAddress.Text = reader["Address"].ToString();
        txtCountry.Text = reader["Country"].ToString();
        txtPhone.Text = reader["Phone"].ToString();
        txtFax.Text = reader["Fax"].ToString();
        txtClinic.Text = reader["Clinic"].ToString();
        txtReferredBy.Text = reader["ReferingFactor"].ToString();
        txtWebSite.Text = reader["WebSite"].ToString();
        txtReceiptNumber.Text = reader["Receipt"].ToString();
        txtDeviceType.Text = reader["DeviceType"].ToString();
        txtDeviceSerialNumber.Text = reader["DeviceSerialNumber"].ToString();
        txtPaymentType.Text = reader["PaymentType"].ToString();
        txtDevicePrice.Text = reader["DevicePrice"].ToString();
        txtClientUserName.Text = reader["PersonUserName"].ToString();
        txtClientPassword.Text = reader["PersonPassword"].ToString();
        txtComments.Text = reader["Comment"].ToString();
```

The save button:

```
string personType = ddlType.SelectedValue;
        string firstName = txtFirstName.Text;
        string lastName = txtLastName.Text;
        string address = txtAddress.Text;
        string country = txtCountry.Text;
        string phone = txtPhone.Text;
        string fax = txtFax.Text;
        string clinic = txtClinic.Text;
        string referredBy = txtReferredBy.Text;
        string website = txtWebSite.Text;
        string receiptNumber = txtReceiptNumber.Text;
        string deviceType = txtDeviceType.Text;
        string deviceSerialNumber = txtDeviceSerialNumber.Text;
        string paymentType = txtPaymentType.Text;
        string devicePrice = txtDevicePrice.Text;
        string clientUserName = txtClientUserName.Text;
        string clientPassword = txtClientPassword.Text;
        string comments = txtComments.Text;



        string id = Request.QueryString["id"];

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =" + Server.MapPath("path to DB"));
        string str = "update table set PersonType = ?, FirstName = ?, LastName = ?, Address = ?, Country = ?, Phone = ?, Fax = ?, Clinic = ?, ReferingFactor = ?, WebSite = ?, Receipt = ?, DeviceType = ?, DeviceSerialNumber = ?, PaymentType = ?, DevicePrice = ?,PersonUserName = ?, PersonPassword = ?, Comment = ? where ID = ?";
        using (conn)
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PersonType", personType);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", firstName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", lastName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address", address);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Country", country);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Phone", phone);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Fax", fax);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Clinic", clinic);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ReferingFactor", referredBy);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("WebSite", website);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Receipt", receiptNumber);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DeviceType", deviceType);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DeviceSerialNumber", deviceSerialNumber);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PaymentType", paymentType);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DevicePrice", devicePrice);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PersonUserName", clientUserName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PersonPassword", clientPassword);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Comment", comments);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PersonID", id);

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

What I am doing wrong and how I make it right?
Sorry if this ask before but I did not find the answer.
I think it has something with postback, am I right?

If you need more information, please write me what is needed.
Thanks
( I edit some of the words on the command string)

Comment: Can you show what is being threw? Any error?

Comment: can you show your pageload function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use **Page.IsPostback** Property like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
             // Put your code inside this.
             string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
             OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =" + Server.MapPath("path to DB"));
    OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand("select * from table where ID=" + id, conn);
    OleDbDataReader reader;
    conn.Open();
    reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read();
    ddlType.SelectedIndex = (Convert.ToInt32(reader["PersonType"]) - 1); // -1 to fix position, list is zero based. type 1(0) = PP type 2(1) = DC

    txtFirstName.Text = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
    txtLastName.Text = reader["LastName"].ToString();
    txtAddress.Text = reader["Address"].ToString();
    txtCountry.Text = reader["Country"].ToString();
    txtPhone.Text = reader["Phone"].ToString();
    txtFax.Text = reader["Fax"].ToString();
    txtClinic.Text = reader["Clinic"].ToString();
    txtReferredBy.Text = reader["ReferingFactor"].ToString();
    txtWebSite.Text = reader["WebSite"].ToString();
    txtReceiptNumber.Text = reader["Receipt"].ToString();
    txtDeviceType.Text = reader["DeviceType"].ToString();
    txtDeviceSerialNumber.Text = reader["DeviceSerialNumber"].ToString();
    txtPaymentType.Text = reader["PaymentType"].ToString();
    txtDevicePrice.Text = reader["DevicePrice"].ToString();
    txtClientUserName.Text = reader["PersonUserName"].ToString();
    txtClientPassword.Text = reader["PersonPassword"].ToString();
    txtComments.Text = reader["Comment"].ToString();
            }

        }
```

Hope it works..

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was something with the postback, but did not remembered where to enter it.

Comment: if it solves your problem then don't forget to like it as a answer.thanks

Comment: Thanks Rahul, I used

if (Page.isPostBack)
{
return;
}

but I think it not working, can I use what I wrote?
What is the difference between your code and my code?
My code need to be the first thing on page load?

Comment: if you will not use (!Page.IsPostback) then each and evry time you will get old value because it call your select query again and again.Postback means - to check that this page is first time postback to server or not.When you will use Page.IsPostback then your select query will call only once and if you refresh your page again then it will not go inside Page.IsPostback and your select function will not call and you will not get old values...hope you understand..

Comment: Thanks, I understand, but there really difference between 
if (Page.isPostBask) {return;} when I place it first on the page_load or the code you gave me?, what is better?

Answer (score 1):

Its beacause you are passing old values to database.

Pass the new values in textbox in update queries.

**Sample:**

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =" + Server.MapPath("path to DB"));
        string str = "update table set PersonType = ?, FirstName = ?, LastName = ?, Address = ?, Country = ?, Phone = ?, Fax = ?, Clinic = ?, ReferingFactor = ?, WebSite = ?, Receipt = ?, DeviceType = ?, DeviceSerialNumber = ?, PaymentType = ?, DevicePrice = ?,PersonUserName = ?, PersonPassword = ?, Comment = ? where ID = ?";
        using (conn)
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", lastName);
                .
                .
                .
            }
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

when page load for first time only then u should load data to controls

```
if (!IsPostBack)
            {
txtFirstName.Text = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
        txtLastName.Text = reader["LastName"].ToString();
        txtAddress.Text = reader["Address"].ToString();
        txtCountry.Text = reader["Country"].ToString();
        txtPhone.Text = reader["Phone"].ToString();
        txtFax.Text = reader["Fax"].ToString();
        txtClinic.Text = reader["Clinic"].ToString();
        txtReferredBy.Text = reader["ReferingFactor"].ToString();
        txtWebSite.Text = reader["WebSite"].ToString();
        txtReceiptNumber.Text = reader["Receipt"].ToString();
        txtDeviceType.Text = reader["DeviceType"].ToString();
        txtDeviceSerialNumber.Text = reader["DeviceSerialNumber"].ToString();
        txtPaymentType.Text = reader["PaymentType"].ToString();
        txtDevicePrice.Text = reader["DevicePrice"].ToString();
        txtClientUserName.Text = reader["PersonUserName"].ToString();
        txtClientPassword.Text = reader["PersonPassword"].ToString();
        txtComments.Text = reader["Comment"].ToString();
    }
```